# Python blurred image creation, to create a beautifully colored painting from black to white

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, image-processing

on Pyhton I wanted to create a picture that goes from black to white, and I wrote the following code. But I think I'm doing a very small mistake, and that's the result.

[image]

I actually wanted to create a similar image. Can you see where I made a mistake?

[image]

```
  import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
width = 100
height = 100
img = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
xx, yy=np.mgrid[:height, :width]
circle = (xx - 50)**2 + (yy- 50)**2
for x in range (img.shape[0]):
    for y in range (img.shape[1]):
        intensity = circle[x][y]
        img[x][y]= intensity
Image.fromarray(img, 'L').show()
Image.fromarray(img, 'L').save ('circlebad.png', 'PNG')
```

<----------------------------------Edit---------------------------------------->

When I insert; `intensity = intensity / 512`my problem solved. Last codes;

```
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    width = 100
    height = 100
    img = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
    xx, yy=np.mgrid[:height, :width]
    circle = (xx - 50)**2 + (yy- 50)**2
    for x in range (img.shape[0]):
        for y in range (img.shape[1]):
            intensity = circle[x][y]
            intensity = intensity / 512
            img[x][y]= intensity
    Image.fromarray(img, 'L').show()
    Image.fromarray(img, 'L').save ('circlebad.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this, but here's a question. Does intensity have a limit? Possibly normalize by the largest possible in the square?

Comment: The maximum value of `intensity` is `2 * 50**2`, but you probably want its maximum value to be 255.  (It looks like anything higher is taken modulo 256.)  So you need to multiply the result by 255 and divide by the actual maximum.  Bear in mind the actual maximum will change if the width/height change.

Comment: Your `for` loops don't make much sense. The main point of using Numpy is to let Numpy do the looping for you, at compiled speed. So if ever you find yourself writing a Python loop that loops over the indices of a Numpy array there's probably a much faster way to do it.

Comment: FWIW, I think your "wrong" version is more interesting. ;)

Comment: I solved. When I added "intensity = intensity / 512" value after intesity define, I got what I wanted.   

`intensity = circle[x][y]
intensity = intensity / 512
img[x][y]= intensity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, the reason you are getting the output in the top image is because the intensities need to be in `range(256)`, and Numpy arithmetic is effectively doing `% 256` on the values your code is producing.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

width = height = 320
radius = (width - 1) / 2
xx, yy = np.mgrid[:height, :width]

# Compute the raw values
circle = (xx - radius) ** 2 + (yy - radius) ** 2

#Brightness control
maxval = 255
valscale = maxval / (2 * radius ** 2)
circle = (circle * valscale).astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(circle, 'L')
img.show()
img.save('circle.png')
```

**output: circle.png**

[image: greyscale circle]

Comment: Thank you! It is the answer to the question I was looking for exactly. I was extremely confident in my own coding but I am very new to pyhton yet.

Comment: @MahmutBedir this has nothing to do with Python, you will find the same problem in any language.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hi Mark, alternatively I want to solve this problem with use for loops on Python. Do you have any idea that?

Comment: @MahmutBedir As I said earlier, if you do this by looping in Python over every pixel it will be _much_ slower than letting Numpy do the looping at C speed.