# Composing an arbitrarily long composition of Images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, python-imaging-library

Inspired by [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-composition-in-python/) for composing simple functions and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512983/python-blurred-image-creation-to-create-a-beautifully-colored-painting-from-bla) using np.mgrid to display a function; I'm attempting to compose a chain images created by various functions functions. I'm able to get the below program to generate an image for 1 variable functions, but I hope to be able to use 2 variable functions though I am unsure how to modify lambda and the input to `ComposedImageArray`.

```
from PIL import Image
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np, random

def functionArray(depth = 0):
    FunctList = []

    for x in range(depth):
        func = random.choice(functions)
        FunctList.append(func)
    return FunctList

def composite_function(*func):
    def compose(f, g):
        return lambda x: f(g(x))

    return reduce(compose, func, lambda x: x)

def XSquared(xx):
    return xx ** 2

def YSquared(yy):
    return yy ** 2

def BothXandY(xx,yy):
    return xx + yy

def SquaredXandY(xx,yy):
    return xx**2 + yy**2

width = height = 256
xx, yy = np.mgrid[:height, :width]

testing = np.ones((height, width)) * 2 #Make an array as the initial input image
functions = (XSquared,YSquared) #Possible functions to select from
# functions = (BothXandY,SquaredXandY()) - I'd like to be able to use functions of two variables
TheList = functionArray(10) #Gives a random list of functions chosen from functions.
ComposedImageArray = composite_function(*TheList) #Combines creates an image iteratively by composing each of the functions in TheList
print(TheList) #Gives a list of functions
composedImage = ComposedImageArray(testing)
# print(composedImage)
img = Image.fromarray(composedImage, 'L')# Creates an PIL image.
img.show()
img.save('Composed.png')
```

Comment: In your question, two things need clarification: what is the input image (is it the mgrid? or xx? or circle)?  What are the simple functions?  You write `functions = (onlyX,onlyY,XSquared,YSquared)`, but these are arrays not functions.

Comment: And finally, `functionArray` only seems to randomly pick 2 functions, it is (imho) unnecessary to your question. Could it be removed to simplify the question?

Comment: @Demi-Lune. I tried to pass in xx but get an error: "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" So I'm unsure of how to get xx (or any mgrid in to a format to pass initially (if this is even what needs to be passed in). The functionArray() is needed to pick a chain of functions such that one function can be passed in to another.

Comment: I meant: since your variable `functions` is **not** a list of functions, passing them to `composite_function` cannot work (hence the error "object is not callable"). `functions` must be functions! For instance: `onlyX = lambda arr: arr[0]` would be ok: it is a function that takes the 1st coordinate of a 2D array.  But since you are not giving us an input image nor a list of functions to apply to it, your question is incomplete for the moment.

Comment: @Demi-Lune, Thanks for the advice, really appreciated, it helped solve the problem. I am now able to get an output and from looking breakpoints inside the functions it looks like consecutive squaring is happening which means that functions are getting passed in to others. So (I hope) the first problem is solved. Any idea on how I might change lambda and the input to ComposedImageArray? Also, I figure it may be hard to go back and forth between functions of one and two variables, so I could make them all of two variables and just pass one of the variables to be 0-arrays to get only 1 variable.

Comment: `Xsquared` and `Ysquared` are 2 functions that do exactly the same thing: take one argument and square it. Why do you do that?

Comment: Another thing: you want functions of 2 variables. Do you expect to pass them two images as input data?  Since you have your random pick in a list of functions, this cannot work: you want to compose functions that all take 1 arg as input and return 1 value (both images in your case). If you add 2-var functions in the game, they will need 2 input variables (which in turn would be the output of a previous function call ... so all your functions in theList should take 2 input images and return 2 images)

Comment: @Demi-Lune. Yeah, good point, they do the same thing, I was just making multiple functions for the random function picker. Ok, so you're saying that I can't mix and match functions that return 1 variable and 2 variables (if I am correct). I however should be able to create all functions that take in two images and put out two images (to the next function) and still get the program to work, is this correct? Seems to me that this should work, even if I have to pack two images in a tuple and unpack them in the next function, I don't know if I would have to do that though. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228179/discussion-between-relative0-and-demi-lune).